# Finding cause of responder flow exception

Tags: corda

I'm having responder flow failing with `IllegalStateException`, however the initiating one fails with `UnexpectedFlowEndException`. Is it possible to somehow get the information about the original exception ?

Comment: Could you share the logs of the error? 
At first glance, the `IllegalStateException` seems to be the original exception that is causing it. For example, it could be your state is not built correctly or the state has been consumed.

Answer (score 0):

only if you wrap the original exception in something that extends `FlowException`, you need something like this

```
@InitiatedBy(InitiatorFlow::class)
class ResponderFlow : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        try {
            // Your logic
        } catch(e : IllegalStateException) {
            throw FlowException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

note that `InitiatorFlow` will receive a `FlowException` containing an `IllegalStateException` as its cause